# Baked Image Texture is Blurry

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I've followed quite a few tutorials on how to bake - been over advanced options etc. So I'm pretty familiar.

One issue I'm running into is that the baked image texture is blurry compared to the original image texture.

The original image texture is 6144 x 4756.

I scaled the original image texture in the mapping node to 3.0.

I created a new image in UV editor using the same dimensions.

The result is blurry / not as sharp.

Could this be due to scaling the original image texture?

**EDIT:**

Things I've tried:

- Applying transformations before unwrapping
- Creating a higher resolution image in UV editor
- Increasing render samples
- Changing from Branched Path Tracing to Path Tracing
- Unwrapping with correct aspect ratio
- Scaling UV's to fit UV editor frame
- Plugging the original texture directly into Diffuse node before baking
- Flat shading the objects
- .png instead of .jpg
- Saving baked image with highest quality
- Praying

Sharp (Original Texture):

[image]

Blurry (After Baking)

[image]

Node Setup:

[image]

Render / Bake Settings:

[image]

Comment: Since it's mostly blurry ar the edges, have you tried setting your model to flat shading before baking?

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz I just tried you suggestion and it's still blurry. Also it's blurry everywhere - if you look at the wood cracks you can see a difference.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: @PraxisVisuals Yeah, I switched over to Substance ;)